# Java Recursion Parameter Value

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, arraylist, tree

From a binary tree, you want to create a 2-d arraylist where each arraylist within the main arraylist contains all the nodes of a binary tree on a single level, for all of the levels. I understand how to do this recursively with DFS but I am very confused about why it possible to get the correct answer by passing in the arraylist I want to populate as a parameter in the recursive function.

The header of my recursive function looks like this

```
createLevelLinkedList(TreeNode current, ArrayList<LinkedList<TreeNode>> lists, int level)
```

With basecase:

```
if (current == null) return;
```

As the tree is traversed, the current node will be appended to its corresponding arraylist within "lists". Within the recursive function there there two recursive calls to move the function to the child nodes of current:

```
createLevelLinkedList(current.left, lists, level + 1);
createLevelLinkedList(current.right, lists, level + 1);
```

Suppose there is a tree that looks like this

```
          5
     3         8
 2      4          9
```

With depth first tree traversal, after the first return, we will have TreeNode "2" is the top object in the stack, then "3". When TreeNode "3" is current and the function calls

```
    createLevelLinkedList(current.right, lists, level + 1);
```

To push TreeNode "4" onto the stack, how can lists contains TreeNode "2" if it actually does and what is really going in memory?

The code I am referencing can be found on Github: https://github.com/gaylemcd/ctci/blob/master/java/Chapter%204/Question4_4/QuestionDFS.java

```
public static void createLevelLinkedList(TreeNode root, ArrayList<LinkedList<TreeNode>> lists, int level) 
{
  if (root == null) return;
  LinkedList<TreeNode> list = null;
  if (lists.size() == level) { // Level not contained in list
    list = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
/* Levels are always traversed in order. So, if this is the first time we've visited level i,
 * we must have seen levels 0 through i - 1. We can therefore safely add the level at the end. */
    lists.add(list);
  } else {
    list = lists.get(level);
  }
  list.add(root);
  createLevelLinkedList(root.left, lists, level + 1);
  createLevelLinkedList(root.right, lists, level + 1);
}
```

Comment: You didn't show the code in which you add nodes to your list, so how can we answer your question? Why don't you post the full code of `createLevelLinkedList`?

Comment: Yes, for sure. I'm looking at some code on GitHub
https://github.com/gaylemcd/ctci/blob/master/java/Chapter%204/Question4_4/QuestionDFS.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should understand that there's only one `ArrayList` instance passed to the `createLevelLinkedList` method. Each recursive call to `createLevelLinkedList` receives a reference to the same instance of the `ArrayList`.

Therefore, once the `TreeNode` 2 is added to the `ArrayList` (or, to be exact, to one of the `LinkedList`s contained within the `ArrayList`), it stays there throughout the execution of the recursive method. It doesn't disappear when the invocation of `createLevelLinkedList` that added it to the list returns.

Comment: I see. I think my main confusion comes from `level` not changing value in the previous stack frames after `TreeNode` 2 is added to `lists`. Is it because level is a primitive type?

Comment: @ArjunPatel Java is a pass by value language, so it doesn't matter whether you are passing a primitive or reference variable to a method. In both cases the method can only change the variable locally, which doesn't affect previous stack frames. The `lists` variable also remains unchanged. The thing that changes is the state of the `lists` object (as you add linked lists and elements to it).